# Проверка года на високосность

Tags: php

Нужно проверить год (не текущий) на високосность. Нашел такой алгоритм:

1. Год делится на 400 -> високосный -> конец
2. Год делится на 100 -> не високосный -> конец
3. Год делится на 4 -> високосный -> конец
4. Год не високосный -> конец
5. Всё

Он верен? 
(Как число может делиться на 400 и не делиться на 100?)

Comment: Алгоритм верен, 1 пункт проверяет такие года как 1600, 2000 (високосные), а второй - 1700, 1800, 1900 (невисокосные)

Comment: Спасибо! А то уже голову сломал)

Comment: Он верен? (Как число может делиться на 400 и не делиться на 100?)//Легко. Если число делится на 400, оно делится и на 4 и на 100. Проблема в том, что после проверки делимости на 400 мы завершаем выполнение, дальнейшие проверки не происходят. Именно поэтому сначала идет проверка на 400, потом на 100, потом на 4, а не наоборот: для экономии. Живой человек сначала поделит на 4, потом на 100, потом на 400, потеряв на этом до трех действий.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function isLeap($year)
{
    return date("L", mktime(0,0,0, 7,7, $year));
}
```

Если год высокостный то возвращает 1 иначе 0

**UPD:**

ну или так :) Как говорится, для любителей сложных путей :)

```
function isLeap($y){return $y % 400 == 1 || ($y % 100 != 0 && ($y & 3) == 0);}
```

Comment: +1. Но это скучное решение. =) Мы не ищем легких путей.

Comment: Небольшая поправка: `$y % 400 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

А не проще оставить одно условие если остаток от деления на 4 будет равно 0, то високосный, отлично от нуля обычный?

Comment: Это и делается в третьем пункте.

Comment: Тогда вопрос в качестве ликбеза для меня, а зачем остальные пункты?

Comment: Степан, 1900(1100,1300,1400,1500,1700,1800) год делится на 4, но високосным не является. Так устроен календарь. Насчет первого тысячелетия утверждать не буду, но походу тот самый временной сдвиг, из-за которого мы празднуем октябрьскую революцию в ноябре, а новый год дважды(старый новый стили) - это как раз компенсация набежавших дней за время летоисчисления. Погуглите.

Comment: Спасибо, честно говоря не знал)))

Comment: 1100 1300 - это все таки високосные. почитайте [википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C) детальнее. Причем, к примеру в России 1900 год был високосным, а  в других странах - нет... так что...

Comment: Про 1300 не нашел. Цитату, плиз

Comment: Новый календарь не распространяется в прошлое, не находите, что это логично?

Comment: По моему, это правило вычисления "современных" дат. К датам веков 5 назад не относится (в 1582 году римский папа Григорий XIII ввел календарь, в котором такое правило вычисления високосных лет).